# Float left, center, and float right 3 div on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `div` that contain both text and image.

I would like to show them on the same line with the 1st `div` on left, 2nd `div` in the center, and the 3rd `div` on the right. I can do CSS for the 1st `div` and the 3rd `div`. The 2nd `div` causes me trouble.
I have the follow codes so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <style type="text/css">
         .onLeft {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
         }
         .onRight {
            display: inline;
            float: right;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="onLeft"><h3>Left</h3><img src=images/left.png></div>
      <div class="onCentre"><h3>Centre</h3><img src=images/centre.png></div>
      <div class="onRight"><h3>Right</h3><img src=images/right.png></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you specifically need to use floats like that? Can't you just float:left; all of them (so they get on one line one after the other)? Alternatively try using flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/, look for align-items: stretch).

Comment: Try adding `float: left` to all three divs. Or, and some will scream at me for suggesting this, make a table of one row (`tr`) and inside have three `td` tags with each image inside.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit. I would like the 3 div sits at the left, centre, and the right of the web page all on the same horizontal line. Table wouldn't work.

Comment: Do your page/columns need to be of fixed width or flexible/responsive.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to have a fix width as the 3 div can have variable width

So:

## option 1

- set `display:table/table-cell`

```css
section {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}
article {
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>article 1</article>
  <article>article 2</article>
  <article>article 3</article>
</section>
```

## option 2

- set `display:flex`

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}
article {
  border: 1px red solid;
  flex:1
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>article 1</article>
  <article>article 2</article>
  <article>article 3</article>
</section>
```

Comment: I do not want to have a fix width as the 3 div can have variable width.

Comment: Fix width is not practical since the screen width is not know. If the screen is wider than the total width, there will be spaces left on the right side and I want the 3rd div sits all to the right

Comment: You can safely remove the witdth in most of the options above.. I just use for demo purposes.

Comment: @pat see updated answer, to use without fixed `width`

Answer (score 0):

So your requirement is to have three divs spread on each part of the page left, center and right. You are not really looking for a column layout. You might be able to do this using an additional div. Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jhuk14n/) link which is one way of doing this.

```
.onLeft {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.onCentre {
  float: left;
  width:40%;
  background-color: red;
}
.realCentre {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.onRight {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: then the 1st div and the 2nd div will stick together

Comment: @pat Ok so your requirement is little different. I updated my answer with a jsfiddle link which shows how you can cheat a little to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use inline-blocks instead of floating.

CSS:

```
div {display: inline-block}
.onLeft {width: 30%}
.onCenter {width: 40%}
.onRight {width: 30%}
```